# Creating an install script on a locked-down computer

Tags: powershell

We have a group of users that I need to run a flash installer on, the computers are locked down and you need to run any installer as the local admin for it to succeed.

I'm looking for a way to let a end user run a powershell/cmd script and have that script execute as the local admin, without storing any plain text passwords within the script. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could "encrypt" the password using `ConvertTo-SecureString` and `ConvertFrom-SecurString`, but the key to "encrypt" your password needs to be defined in your script. And the users can read the script-file, and convert the securestring back to clear-text by running a few PowerShell lines. Why can't you use GPO (or a software distribution system if have one) to install Flash on the computers?

Answer (score 1):

Just to put it in an answer, @Frode F. is right, the best way to do this is to use Group Policy to install it.

At my org, we use GPO's to install Flash, Reader, Office, etc. and it's done in thousands of companies. Not only is it fairly easy to create, but also allows you to control the versions and updates of products that you install, and best of all, you need no passwords or anything (the Domain Controller *is* the administrator to your computers)

There are dozens of guides out there to do this, for ex. See: [Deploy Adobe Flash Player With Group Policy](http://deployhappiness.com/deploy-adobe-flash-player-with-group-policy/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by providing a PowerShell script which connects using PowerShell Remoting to the local computer through a specifically configured endpoint. You would then configure that endpoint to run as a user which will have the necessary permissions but the endpoint will also be constrained to execute only the command(s) which you have created (which would install flash, for example).

For more information about session configurations, I suggest reading up on

```
Get-Help about_session_configurations
Get-Help about_session_configuration_files

Get-Command *sessionconfiguration*
```

Or, to get a list of which things you can read up more on (in case it changes between versions), just run the following two commands:

```
Get-Help *session_configuration*
Get-Help *sessionconfiguration*
```

Edit: Do be sure to create the session configuration file using the `-LanguageMode NoLanguage` parameter to make sure the user is not allowed to run anything at all other than what you have provided as explicitly allowed. From the help-file regarding that parameter with that value:

```
-- NoLanguage: Users may run cmdlets and functions, but are not permitted to use any language elements, such as script blocks, variables, or operators.
```

Comment: Nice idea. I didn't bother suggesting it since it's a LOT of work for such a small task, but it is doable. :)

Comment: Would I need to have the users credentials at hand in order to run the  script as them?

Comment: No, the endpoint would allow the users which you want to allow to connect to it and any commands run using that endpoint would be run as the admin user you have specified when you registered the endpoint. The script from the user perspective would only connect to a PSSession on the given endpoint using their own credentials (which is the default if you don't specify credentials) and run the command.